Where are the 32nd century Klingons?
Perhaps I missed something, but I don't recall any appearance or mention of Klingons from Star Trek: Discovery season 3 forward.
Is there any mention or appearance of the Klingons in the 32nd century?
If not, is there any commentary by producers or writers on what happened to them or on the decision to leave the question of their fate open?

There's speculation that they realized the redesign was unpopular and therefore removed them entirely, but it seems entirely speculatory.

@fez:  why do you keep removing that?  That's part of the question

I wondered. @fez isn't thinking that you're referring to this question are they?

@ThePopMachine I have no clue what that part of the question means. If you’re referencing something in universe I’m sorry, but it sounds like meta commentary that should be removed

Ooooh I see, a decision to leave the question “of their existence” open. My bad!

@fez:  clarified.

You know. Clinging on. Ha ha ha ha ha hm.

@FuzzyBoots I disliked almost everything about Discovery, but I "get" what they were doing with the Klingons..  they were trying to make them more alien and distance them from man-in-a-costume Trek. Unfortunately, the makeup was really bad and distracting... even worse than the original they were trying to distance themselves from! I've always found Star Trek's costumes/makeup really silly across the board (due to budget I guess) but this one took the cake.

As per this Reddit Post, there are references in Seasons 3 and 4.

They are around. The Klingon Empire has been referenced on star maps. Season 3 Episode 8 had a map
https://twitter.com/gaghyogi49/status/1335302388127764490/photo/1
https://twitter.com/strangenewtakes/status/1329523031216168962/photo/1
Season 3, Episode 5 has a map of all 4 quadrants.
https://twitter.com/TrekCore/status/1327988685518811142
They get name dropped a couple times in season 4.
s04e07 - Book: What about with the Klingons? How is this different? Burnham: I had an intrinsic understanding of Klingon culture.
s04e08 - Haz: While you two were strutting around like Klingons in a disco, I reached out to some of my regulars and found two who'd be happy to take the isolynium off your hands so you can get back to your relationship whatnot.
s04e10 - Kovich: No, they're here in case you feel like translating confirmation bias from Federation Standard into Klingon.
s04e11 - Jett Reno: When you have to power through, nothing beats the bitter elixir of Klingon warriors.


Only the first quote really counts for anything because it shows that Book and Burnham encountered Klingons.   Everything else can just be figures of speech about a long dead culture.

Actually, I take it back.  What is Book referencing in that quote?  Maybe he's just referring to something that Burnham told him about in the 23rd century.

That's fair, but I figured they at least counted as references, which suggests that the Time Wars haven't wiped them out retroactively. :-D

Upon review, I really do think the intent of that line is Book asking why Burnham's attitude toward taking action against the Klingons is different than her position on taking action regarding Ten-C.  He is referring to whatever Burnham did in the 23rd century.  Transcript follows.

BURNHAM: I wasn't trying to speak out against you.
BOOK: I know. But you've always been the first to jump into action, take on the enemy, odds be damned. What about with the Klingons? How is this different?
BURNHAM: I had an intrinsic understanding of Klingon culture. We don't have any knowledge about Species Ten-C. And I understand the appeal of Tarka's plan, but the risks are too great.
